# Alternative way to read azure functions log

Tags: azure, logging, azure-functions

I write to Azure Functions log using ILogger, e.g.:

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("1 0 0 * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer,
                      ILogger log,
                      ExecutionContext context
{
    log.LogInformation($"{context.FunctionName} function executed at: {DateTime.UtcNow}");
```

I use Azure portal to read logs, usually it works fine, but sometimes I got the following:

[image]

and no matter, success or failure of function execution

as I understand, it's a bug of Azure Portal.

Any alternative way to read these logs? as I assume, I can use Kusto Query Language (KQL), but can't configure query to get data the same way as I can see on Azure Portal

My `host.json` file is:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "batchSize": 1
    }
  },
  "functionTimeout": "03:00:00",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the logLevel set to in your host.json.  There is sampling settings for App Insights, that might have impact on your log data.

Comment: added my `host.json` file to post

Comment: Under the logging, set `LogLevel` to Information level, and if you are in development environment and want to see detailed logs, you can set `isEnabled` to false under `applicationInsights`. Also, remember that after your function is called, it may take about 5mins for your logs to appear in Azure portal.

Comment: As mentioned you can't get data same as azure portal using KQL may I know what type of logs you are searching for?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the **File System Logs** in the **Logs** Console of the **Test/Run** Page or **Log Stream** under **Monitoring** Section of the Azure Function App during the running state.

[image: AzF-FileSystemLogsRepro]

**File System Logs <- Log Stream <- Monitoring (Left Index Menu) of the Function App**:

[image: LogStreamMenu]

In the Storage Account associated with the Azure Function App, all these f**ile system logs** will be available.

**`Storage Account > File Shares (under Data Storage) > Your Function App > LogFiles > Application > Functions > Host`**

[image: FileSystemLogFilesinHost]

In the path of **`Storage Account > File Shares (under Data Storage) > Your Function App > LogFiles > Application > Functions > Function > Your Function Name >`** You can see the console result (Application Logs - Execution results/failed result/error data) of the function.

[image: AppLogsinFunction]

**In Kudu Explorer, you can see the same Files/Logs with more details using the traces, requests and filter query keywords which gives the information from the Azure Function App Requests and Response logs as shown in the first Gif Image.**